# map/set iterator not dereferencable while serialization

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

I am serializing a class using the following code and in debug version I would occasionally get the `map/set iterator not dereferencable` assertion. This is my code

```
void SomeMethod(MyCollection &hf)
 {
   boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss); 
   oa << hf;
   std::string serialized = ss.str(); 
   ....
   ....
   //do something with the string...
 }
```

The object that I am trying to serialize is as follows

```
class MyCollection
{
 private:
 typedef std::map<int,ActCollection> Ctype;
 Ctype Accts
 //Setters and getters not shown

 friend class boost::serialization::access; 
 template <typename Archive> 
 void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) 
 { 
  ar & Accts;
 } 
};
```

Any suggestion on why I might be getting that error ?

Comment: Do you have other threads fiddling with your collection? Or is it a single threaded application?

Comment: Currently its just one thread

Comment: There is no way to understand what is wrong with your code, without code. May be there is some memory-corrupt in your code, or something like. There is no anything about `ActCollection` for example...

Comment: Does my sample code that I posted seem correct ?

Comment: @MistyD yes, it's perfectly correct (there is no anything about `ss` variable), but serialize function is right.

Comment: Show us how do you call `SomeMethod(collection)` and where `collection` is instantiated and where it is destroyed.